# Weird edge on iOS, only on some devices

Tags: ios, view

I have this weird issue. Someone was working with this code in meantime but I have no idea what is changed and no idea where to search for to find fix for this. Issue is visible on this image:
![1]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxN6pbY6dKUYa0pjZUpPemlFcFk

As you can see edge on iphone6 has some effect applied to it, but it's not visible on iphone6s plus nor on my device (iPad air 2). It's not whole program thing, some separate views are clear on all devices. But I have no idea what this effect is and what for to search.

Every hint what to look for very appreciated.

Thanks a lot for sharing your experience.

Comment: you are working with avcapture???

Comment: Yes - I'm working with avcapture. I found that there was this code which is responsible for adding this effect: detail.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            detail.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
            detail.layer.shadowRadius = 2; //however this doesn't explain why it was behaving different on various screens

Comment: check this link ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850502/ios-crop-video-weird-green-line-left-and-bottom-side-in-video/37850636#37850636